# Screen tearing in various versions of ubuntu/linux mint

Tags: nvidia, tearing

Note: I am very new to linux so I apologize for my ignorance.
Okay I know that this question has been asked several times but I simply cannot fix this seemingly simple issue.

I am facing screen tearing on my laptop with an nvidia gtx 960m gpu. From the start I was facing several issues and I couldnt even boot into the live usb. I was getting the error:While booting up I get the error: 
"ACPI : EC: Fail in evaluating the _REG object of EC device. Broken bios is suspected". . I had to set the boot parameter "nomodeset" to boot into the live usb stick and after installing I had to change the drivers to the proprietary version.
To fix screen tearing I have tried :

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=224942

http://www.howtoeverything.net/linux/issues/finally-no-more-tearing-anywhere-mate-desktop-and-compiz

I have tried several other methods but I cannot post more than 2 links because of my reputation :(

I have tried using both compton and compiz, various versions of drivers on ubuntu 14.04, 15.10, 16.04, 16.10,linux mint 18 cinnamon, kde, mate, xfce but none worked.
The only way I found which seems to work is switching to intel from prime profiles. Is there a way to keep using the nvidia gpu without tearing?
Any help on this topic will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/667466/screen-tearing-in-ubuntu-with-nvidia-intel-graphics

Comment: similar or the same? http://askubuntu.com/questions/760712/how-do-i-remove-screen-tearing-in-16-04-with-nvidia-gtx-960-m

Comment: @Patrick Negus I added it to /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf as his path did not exist but then my laptop straight up refused to boot.

Comment: @fossfreedom I think they are pretty similar but still unsolved :(