# Screen tearing lines and other issues when I watch any videos

Tags: nvidia, video, 18.04, flash

I have many problems on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

First of all my notebook:

Lenovo Y700-15isk, Intel Core i7-6700HQ, 16 GB RAM, NVIDIA GTX 960M 4 GB. SSD 256 GB, and HDD 1 TB.

Ubuntu is installed in dual boot with Windows. Also `/root` (50 GB) and swap (9 GB) installed on SSD, `/home` installed on hard drive (230 GB).

It was EFI installation.

My problem:

When I watch videos on YouTube or something else online, some lines appear. I do not know how to describe it, that's why I attached screenshots:

Image with some lines:

[image: screenshot of video]

[image: screenshot with obvious tearing]

Also sometimes, video freezes for a second (but audio is still running) and it is so bad. Watching video with the help of players on Ubuntu also caused some problems.

VLC does not work any more; I tried to open one file and got an error that it is not decoded, but audio is still working. Default Ubuntu video app is working, but sometimes it freezes.

Trying to change video driver from x.org to Nvidia and vice versa. It is not working. Also tried reinstall flash player, but as I know YouTube videos do not need it.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/760712/how-do-i-remove-screen-tearing-in-16-04-with-nvidia-gtx-960-m

Comment: No, sometimes i not seen these lines. But they appear when video has fast moves. If you understand what I mean...

Comment: Basically, it's about screen tearing, right?

Comment: I think so, do you see images?