# Why does running Minecraft create window tearing/lag

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, xfce, tearing

I have a Titan X graphic card running on Ubuntu 18.04 + Xfce4 desktop, and I experience tearing while dragging windows when Minecraft is open. I have two monitors, and it seems to always happen to the Minecraft window on my main monitor, but to all windows as soon as I drag them to my secondary monitor. The other windows on my main monitor are a bit irregular.

Before installing these two: `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit gcc-6`, as suggested on [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028830/how-do-i-install-cuda-on-ubuntu-18-04), I only experienced lag between mouse/window, but now I experince tearing/shadows too. Still laggy.

I have tried forcing full composition pipeline on my x-server too, and saving it to my X11 file, as suggested on [this other post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760712/how-do-i-remove-screen-tearing-in-16-04-with-nvidia-gtx-960-m), but no apparent change was to be seen after applying and experiencing a small black-monitor delay (I assume X11 reset).

As soon as I close Minecraft, the issues disappear. I'm uncertain on what Minecraft uses for their graphics, but I've been emulating games in Proton through Steam without any issue alike this one. As soon as I enter the menu of the game, the tearing returns. I don't need to enter a world, so I really don't believe it's a resource problem.

I'm not completely certain which repository I used to install my Nvidia drivers, but `apt list nvidia*` gives me a fairly long list of bionic,bionic-updates nvidia versions:

```
nvidia-304/bionic 304.137-0ubuntu2 amd64
nvidia-304-dev/bionic 304.137-0ubuntu2 amd64
nvidia-304-updates/bionic 304.137-0ubuntu2 amd64
nvidia-304-updates-dev/bionic 304.137-0ubuntu2 amd64
nvidia-331/bionic-updates,bionic 340.107-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-331-dev/bionic-updates,bionic 340.107-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-331-updates/bionic-updates,bionic 340.107-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-331-updates-dev/bionic-updates,bionic 340.107-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-331-updates-uvm/bionic-updates,bionic 340.107-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-331-uvm/bionic-updates,bionic 340.107-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-340/bionic-updates,bionic 340.107-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-340-dev/bionic-updates,bionic 340.107-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-340-updates/bionic-updates,bionic 340.107-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-340-updates-dev/bionic-updates,bionic 340.107-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-340-updates-uvm/bionic 340.96-0ubuntu2 amd64
nvidia-340-uvm/bionic-updates,bionic 340.107-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-346/bionic 352.63-0ubuntu3 amd64
nvidia-346-dev/bionic 352.63-0ubuntu3 amd64
nvidia-346-updates/bionic 352.63-0ubuntu3 amd64
nvidia-346-updates-dev/bionic 352.63-0ubuntu3 amd64
nvidia-352/bionic 361.45.11-0ubuntu4 amd64
nvidia-352-dev/bionic 361.45.11-0ubuntu4 amd64
nvidia-352-updates/bionic 361.45.11-0ubuntu4 amd64
nvidia-352-updates-dev/bionic 361.45.11-0ubuntu4 amd64
nvidia-361/bionic 367.57-0ubuntu5 amd64
nvidia-361-dev/bionic 367.57-0ubuntu5 amd64
nvidia-361-updates/bionic 361.45.11-0ubuntu4 amd64
nvidia-361-updates-dev/bionic 361.45.11-0ubuntu4 amd64
nvidia-367/bionic 375.82-0ubuntu3 amd64
nvidia-367-dev/bionic 375.82-0ubuntu3 amd64
nvidia-375/bionic 384.111-0ubuntu1 amd64
nvidia-375-dev/bionic 384.111-0ubuntu1 amd64
nvidia-384/bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-384-dev/bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-387/bionic 390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-387-dev/bionic 390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-390/bionic 390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-390-dev/bionic 390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-cg-dev/bionic 3.1.0013-3 amd64
nvidia-cg-doc/bionic,bionic 3.1.0013-3 all
nvidia-cg-toolkit/bionic 3.1.0013-3 amd64
nvidia-common/bionic-updates 1:0.5.2.3 amd64
nvidia-compute-utils-390/bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-compute-utils-396/bionic 396.54-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-compute-utils-410/bionic 410.104-0ubuntu0~18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-compute-utils-415/bionic 415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-compute-utils-418/bionic,now 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-compute-utils-430/bionic 430.09-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-cuda-dev/bionic,now 9.1.85-3ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-cuda-doc/bionic,bionic,now 9.1.85-3ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
nvidia-cuda-gdb/bionic,now 9.1.85-3ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-cuda-toolkit/bionic,now 9.1.85-3ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
nvidia-current/bionic 304.137-0ubuntu2 amd64
nvidia-current-dev/bionic 304.137-0ubuntu2 amd64
nvidia-dkms-390/bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-dkms-396/bionic 396.54-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-dkms-410/bionic 410.104-0ubuntu0~18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-dkms-415/bionic 415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-dkms-418/bionic,now 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-dkms-430/bionic 430.09-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-driver-390/bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-driver-396/bionic 396.54-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-driver-410/bionic 410.104-0ubuntu0~18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-driver-415/bionic 415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-driver-418/bionic,now 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
nvidia-driver-430/bionic 430.09-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-headless-390/bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-headless-396/bionic 396.54-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-headless-410/bionic 410.104-0ubuntu0~18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-headless-415/bionic 415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-headless-418/bionic 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-headless-430/bionic 430.09-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-headless-no-dkms-390/bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-headless-no-dkms-396/bionic 396.54-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-headless-no-dkms-410/bionic 410.104-0ubuntu0~18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-headless-no-dkms-415/bionic 415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-headless-no-dkms-418/bionic 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-headless-no-dkms-430/bionic 430.09-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-kernel-common-390/bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-kernel-common-396/bionic 396.54-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-kernel-common-410/bionic 410.104-0ubuntu0~18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-kernel-common-415/bionic 415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-kernel-common-418/bionic,now 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-kernel-common-430/bionic 430.09-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-kernel-source-390/bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-kernel-source-396/bionic 396.54-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-kernel-source-410/bionic 410.104-0ubuntu0~18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-kernel-source-415/bionic 415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-kernel-source-418/bionic,now 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-kernel-source-430/bionic 430.09-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-libopencl1-304/bionic 304.137-0ubuntu2 amd64
nvidia-libopencl1-304-updates/bionic 304.137-0ubuntu2 amd64
nvidia-libopencl1-331/bionic-updates,bionic 340.107-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-libopencl1-331-updates/bionic-updates,bionic 340.107-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-libopencl1-340/bionic-updates,bionic 340.107-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-libopencl1-340-updates/bionic-updates,bionic 340.107-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-libopencl1-346/bionic 352.63-0ubuntu3 amd64
nvidia-libopencl1-346-updates/bionic 352.63-0ubuntu3 amd64
nvidia-libopencl1-352/bionic 361.45.11-0ubuntu4 amd64
nvidia-libopencl1-352-updates/bionic 361.45.11-0ubuntu4 amd64
nvidia-libopencl1-361/bionic 367.57-0ubuntu5 amd64
nvidia-libopencl1-361-updates/bionic 361.45.11-0ubuntu4 amd64
nvidia-libopencl1-367/bionic 375.82-0ubuntu3 amd64
nvidia-libopencl1-375/bionic 384.111-0ubuntu1 amd64
nvidia-libopencl1-384/bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-libopencl1-387/bionic 390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-libopencl1-390/bionic 390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-modprobe/bionic 384.111-2 amd64
nvidia-nsight/bionic 9.1.85-3ubuntu1 amd64
nvidia-opencl-dev/bionic,now 9.1.85-3ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-opencl-icd-304/bionic 304.137-0ubuntu2 amd64
nvidia-opencl-icd-304-updates/bionic 304.137-0ubuntu2 amd64
nvidia-opencl-icd-331/bionic-updates,bionic 340.107-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-opencl-icd-331-updates/bionic-updates,bionic 340.107-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-opencl-icd-340/bionic-updates,bionic 340.107-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-opencl-icd-340-updates/bionic-updates,bionic 340.107-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-opencl-icd-346/bionic 352.63-0ubuntu3 amd64
nvidia-opencl-icd-346-updates/bionic 352.63-0ubuntu3 amd64
nvidia-opencl-icd-352/bionic 361.45.11-0ubuntu4 amd64
nvidia-opencl-icd-352-updates/bionic 361.45.11-0ubuntu4 amd64
nvidia-opencl-icd-361/bionic 367.57-0ubuntu5 amd64
nvidia-opencl-icd-361-updates/bionic 361.45.11-0ubuntu4 amd64
nvidia-opencl-icd-367/bionic 375.82-0ubuntu3 amd64
nvidia-opencl-icd-375/bionic 384.111-0ubuntu1 amd64
nvidia-opencl-icd-384/bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-opencl-icd-387/bionic 390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-opencl-icd-390/bionic 390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-prime/bionic-updates,bionic-updates,now 0.8.8.2 all [installed,automatic]
nvidia-profiler/bionic,now 9.1.85-3ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-settings/bionic,now 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-utils-390/bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-utils-396/bionic 396.54-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-utils-410/bionic 410.104-0ubuntu0~18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-utils-415/bionic 415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2 amd64
nvidia-utils-418/bionic,now 418.56-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-utils-430/bionic 430.09-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64
nvidia-visual-profiler/bionic,now 9.1.85-3ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance that your system actually allows Optimus to work! Be glad for that, as Optimus doesn't work 99% of the time on *nix.

in doing so, all nVidia chipsets of any kind don't have support for V-Sync at all, on any Linux distro. Chances are that it's using Intel HD until Optimus goes "oh wait, i need to do this one" and then it swaps over, and since there is no V-Sync at all on nVidia, the entire screen tears.